# Can't use appcompat controls in Xamarin project

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-appcompat

I've been trying to use AppCompat components in my Android Application but for some reason SetContentView method keeps throwing:

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML
>   file line #1: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Stack trace of exception:

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (JniObjectReference instance, JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x000a7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12083 
>     at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00068] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:31 
>     at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (Int32 layoutResID) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4940 
>     at AttendITAndroidClient.LoginActivity.Initialize () [0x00002] in C:\Users\brakm\onedrive\dokumenti\visual studio 2015\Projects\AttendITDesktopClient\AttendITAndroidClient\Activities\LoginActivity.cs:30 
>     --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>       at md5d9765193e278a5bdda80f23f9bd7e090.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
>       at md5d9765193e278a5bdda80f23f9bd7e090.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:29)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>       ... 18 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/AttendITAndroidClient.AttendITAndroidClient-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/AttendITAndroidClient.AttendITAndroidClient-1/lib/x86, /data/app/AttendITAndroidClient.AttendITAndroidClient-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>       ... 24 more
>       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>           ... 27 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Activity is inheriting right class and is using right Theme(AFAIK)(I've tried using "@android:style/Theme.AppCompat" as well)

```
[Activity(Label = "AttendIT Mobile", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat")]
public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

Here are (relevant) project references and components.
[image: Project references and components.]

Am i missing something? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/AttendITLogoWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/UsernameEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PasswordEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Login"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Settings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="No account yet? Create one"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

here is my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Refractored.FloatingActionButton" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="22.0.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

Code that is throwing exception:

```
private void Initialize()
{

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login); //this method throws exception



    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.LoginButton);
    button.Click += LoginButtonOnClick;

    TextView textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Settings);
    textView.Click += SettingsOnClick;

    _loginLoader = new ProgressDialog(this);
    _loginLoader.SetCancelable(false);
    _loginLoader.SetMessage(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.LoginLoaderMessage));

    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
        Name = "basicHttpBinding",
        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        SendTimeout = timeout,
        OpenTimeout = timeout,
        ReceiveTimeout = timeout
    };      
    _client = new AttendITWCFServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.104:55416/AttendITWCFService.svc"));
    _client.TryLoginCompleted += ClientOnTryLoginCompleted;
}

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    Initialize();
}
```

Packages
[image]
Components
[image]

Comment: Show us your code for the respective call! Also have you tried cleaning your solution, deleting your `bin/obj` folders and rebuilding?

Comment: Sometimes cleaning and rebuilding won't do the trick, try closing VS and then clean rebuild your project.

Comment: @JLONG tried everything you guys suggested, sadly nothing worked, added more stuff to answer that i believe might be of use.

Comment: Can you please show your whole components and packages folder? I would like to check on something

Comment: @JLONG Added. Just jeep in mind that this isn't only project in solution soo many of these packages aren't refrenced by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout"
```

Is a **Android Support design library**, on your case, You are missing that Library on your **Package folder** based on the screenshots of your project. Adding this [Android Support Design Library](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportdesign) would solve the problem. Install, close VS, clean rebuild and see of the error still persist. Cheers!

Comment: No Prob. happy coding!